# Wordpress Shortcode not Updating Page for Logged Out Users

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written a very short PHP snippet which works absolutely fine when I am logged in to the site, but which doesn't update the content for logged out users.

The code reads simple text files listed on the server and concatenates the strings together.  The code is as follows:

```
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function php_hybridiser() { 
    

    
    $f_contents = file("/home/aegiswebdesign/htdocs/aegiswebdesign.uk/list_1.txt");
    $line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
    $item_1 = $line;

    $f_contents = file("/home/aegiswebdesign/htdocs/aegiswebdesign.uk/list_2.txt");
    $line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
    $item_2 = $line;
    $hybridiser = $item_1 . " " . $item_2;
    


    return $hybridiser;
    

}


// register shortcode
add_shortcode('hybridiser', 'php_hybridiser');
```

I assume this has to do with the permissions of logged out users to access the files on the server, but I'm really not sure how to check what permissions the function has regarding the files, or for that matter why it seems to be caching a version of the function but not refreshing it.

Function is here, using Wordpress to generate the site and Code Snippets to create the shortcode.  Otherwise I can post details of all the other plugins running if that would be helpful?

https://trojanspeakers.uk/hybridiser/

Comment: I'm seeing a result, but it's always the same on every refresh. Tried 3 different browsers all seeing `Chicken Pirates`. Are you sure you're getting the expected result back from your ? Whats the reason you've chosen to use `.txt` files over, let's say, PHP arrays (`array()`)?

Comment: Purely convenience - I happened to have the files already formatted as txt files.  Your issue is exactly the problem.  When I run the code as a logged-in user, the result changes with every page refresh.

Comment: Most likely you're using some sort of site caching plugin that outputs a cached version for not logged-in user.

Comment: Thanks - it's genuinely good to know that it's not something blindingly obvious that I've done wrong in the code itself.  In terms of caching, the only hit on "cache" in the plugins list is "Clear Cache For Me", and the Varnish cache has been told to exclude that page.  Will give it more thought!